# how to get string from json in java

Tags: java, android, json

> I have one JSONstring like this and get each string form JSONstring...
>
> While running I get thiis error **Error converting result
> java.lang.NullPointerException**
>
> What should I do???

```
{"login":"1","error":"","id":"1","namespace":"dhruv","first_name":"Dhruv","last_name":"Patel","pro_pic_64_url":"URL","pro_pic_100_url":"URL","pro_pic_200_url":"URL"}
```

And my code to parse this data

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
    String login = json.getString("login");
    TextView welcome =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    welcome.setText(login);
    if(login=="1")
    {
        String namespace = json.getString("namespace");
        String id = json.getString("id");
        String first_name = json.getString("first_name");
        String last_name = json.getString("last_name");
        String pro_pic_64_url = json.getString("pro_pic_64_url");
        String pro_pic_100_url = json.getString("pro_pic_100_url");
        String pro_pic_200_url = json.getString("pro_pic_200_url");
        
    }
```

Comment: `if(login=="1")`. First, don't compare content of strings using ==. And second provide the stacktrace please.

Comment: Please post your stacktrace. And please use if(login.equals("1")==true)

Comment: @Milanix `if("1".equals(login))` is sufficient :)

Comment: @ZouZou Please no Yoda conditions. Although they might prevent NullPointers it physically hurts my brain ;-)

Comment: @André But sometimes NPEs hurt more the brain than Yoda conditions =)

Comment: `Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException` your result may be null can you post the full code

Comment: I am quite interested in knowing the difference between if("1".equals(login)) and if(login.equals("1")==true).

Comment: @Milanix `"1".equals(login)` prevents a NullPointerException if `login` is null. The second one doesn't. The `==true` in the second one is unecessary and could also be written in the first one or even better: left out.

Comment: @Milanix `if()` evaluate a boolean expression. Or equals() already returns a boolean so if the contents are equals your condition will be `if(true == true)` which can be simplified with `if(true)`. @André already explains you the second part.

Comment: Thank you guys. Will keep this in mind next time :)

Answer (score 0):

As `login == "1"` almost certainly is false (should use `equals`), probably `welcome` is false, the result of fiendViewById.

Answer (score 0):

Use String [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method for comparison, Use this

```
  if("1".equals(login))
```

instead of

```
  if(login=="1")
```

Comment: This is a mistake, but I don't see why it would cause the crash of the app.

Comment: Probably u may provide this as an comment/suggestion, but not the answer for the question. Becoz, we dont know where the problem resides. @Dhruv Patel please share the  stacktrace to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `data` string (or is it a map?) isn't null and really contains JSON string. 
Then check if your `findViewById` returns a proper TextView or null.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you code, i can only think of "welcome" object to be null. "json" object cannot be null if you are actually passing the response which you have provided. Though login == "1" is wrong, that wouldn't throw a NullPointerException. So only possible is "welcome" object is null or the exception may be in a code snippet which you haven't pasted here.